# Trying to paste a range of cells

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I'm using a loop to select a range of cells, but I'm not getting a range, instead, I'm getting just two cells.

Screen shot of the data I have here:

[image: screenshot]

```
Sub CellWidthAnalysis()

Dim pastecounter As Integer
Dim collength As Integer
Dim colnumber As Integer

'assign counters

pastecounter = 1 'for pasting in correct column
collength = 1  'for keeping track of column length
colnumber = 2       'for number of columns

ActiveSheet.Cells(3, 1).Select
'Now to select first column of data
If colnumber = 2 Then
        Do Until ActiveCell.Value = "Image Name"
            ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
            collength = collength + 1
        Loop
        Range(Cells(collength, 1), Cells(collength, 2)).Select
        Selection.Copy
        Sheets("Sheet2").Select
        Cells(1, 1).Select
        ActiveCell.Offset(2, pastecounter).Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste
        pastecounter = pastecounter + 5
        colnumber = colnumber + 1
Else
End If
```

I think it has something to do with my collength counter- I'm not sure why though. It should count up with the offset right?

But every time the paste is just A# and B# (the cells right before the Image Name string) instead of the range between (3,1) and (3,2) and the cells right before the Image Name.

Thanks for any thoughts!

Comment: Forgot to add: the screenshot just shows the first page of data, it goes down more in columns A and B until the next data set (which starts with the same three row header which I'm taking advantage of in the Do loop)- so I should be getting a range of ~200 cells pasted into worksheet2 instead of just a range of one...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is in your `Range()` that you're selecting for your copy. Try this:

```
Sub CellWidthAnalysis()

Dim pastecounter As Integer
Dim collength As Integer
Dim colnumber As Integer

'assign counters

pastecounter = 1 'for pasting in correct column
collength = 1  'for keeping track of column length
colnumber = 2       'for number of columns

ActiveSheet.Cells(3, 1).Select
'Now to select first column of data
If colnumber = 2 Then
    Do Until ActiveCell.Value = "Image Name"
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
        collength = collength + 1
    Loop
'the difference is here:
    Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(collength, 2)).Copy
    Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(1, 1).Offset(2, pastecounter).Paste
    pastecounter = pastecounter + 5
    colnumber = colnumber + 1
End If
```

The is the critical change:

- You were defining your range by passing the *same* row to both `Cells()` references, thus getting a range 2 columns wide by 1 row tall. I changed it to use row 2 for the starting point. If that needs to change, you'll want to substitute a variable in there.

A couple of general notes on the code:

1. I did away with the `.select` and `selection.copy`. Replaces 2 lines of code with one
2. I got rid of all the `.select` stuff on the `.paste` instruction as well. Simplifies things
3. I'm not sure of the value of the `If colnumber = 2 Then` structure. You assign `colnumber=2`, then immediately check to see if it is still 2. Unless, of course, you removed some looping code that might change that value to simplify your example.

Comment: Hey, Thanks @FreeMan! That did it. I'm pretty new to VBA so the simplifications were handy to see as well. I did have to change the second line of what you added to 'Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(collength, 2)).Paste' because it was running into an error (I think because it wanted me to select the same range I was pasting there, but not sure)

And yeah, I removed part of the code to simplify it, that's why I've got the 'If colnumber = 2 then' part.

Thanks again! It was a huge help and I'm nearly finished writing this thing :D

Comment: Glad I could help, @Sarah. Using the macro recorder is a great way to get started, and it's a great way to figure out what all the fiddley settings are when you're formatting things. It just writes really ugly code... :)